# Light/Shadow doesn't apply on small gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shadow, light

I want to **implement an object in my scene**. If I add it here's what it looks like :

[image: Plane]

It's beautiful, unfortunately, because of the rest of my scene, I have to **apply a scale of 0.0006** :

```
planeObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.0006f, 0.0006f, 0.0006f);
```

And here's what happen, **no light or shadow on the texture of my plane**:

[image: Plane2]

I try to modify my light, here's my parameters:

[image: Light]

Did I miss something, is there a minimum size for the light to be apply?

Comment: If you need to apply such a small scale there is something serious wrong in your scene. This might cause troubles with floating point precision and the shadow near plane is also wrong for this type of scale i guess.

Comment: The shadow near plane is good, only happen on the texture, I know there's something wrong in my scene, but I just want to know if I can do something to make this work with this scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to apply a small scale to a plane. You should be able to model everything in some reasonable scale. Then, you can use the view parameters to zoom into the plane. You don't say what the object sizes are or where the directional light is located. My guess is that the light is inside, behind, or pointing away from plane, thus the flat shading. You should be able to put the light far away from the plane and see if that does anything, then move it closer, if you need some effects, but the sun is pretty far away. ;-)